# I need help on android studio rendering problems

Tags: android-studio

Exception raised during rendering:

> Please change caller according to
>   com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
>   com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException: Please change
>   caller according to
>   com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation   at
>   com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.handleDumbMode(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:854)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.ensureUpToDate(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:803)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.ensureUpToDate(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:787)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.processElements(StubIndexImpl.java:250)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.processElements(StubIndexImpl.java:238)
>     at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.process(StubIndex.java:76)   at
>   com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.process(StubIndex.java:95)   at
>   com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.get(StubIndexImpl.java:227)   at
>   com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.getElements(StubIndex.java:144)   at
>   com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.getElements(StubIndex.java:134)   at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.java.stubs.index.JavaFullClassNameIndex.get(JavaFullClassNameIndex.java:48)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.JavaFileManagerImpl.findClassInIndex(JavaFileManagerImpl.java:145)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.file.impl.JavaFileManagerImpl.findClass(JavaFileManagerImpl.java:138)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementFinderImpl.findClass(PsiElementFinderImpl.java:54)
>     at
>   com.intellij.psi.impl.JavaPsiFacadeImpl.findClass(JavaPsiFacadeImpl.java:99)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction  
>   ... (ApplicationImpl.java:890)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.(BridgeActionBar.java:84)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.(AppCompatActionBar.java:56)

Comment: Do you mind to add the related code? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When the IDE is indexing, if we try to change the values in properties tab, then IndexNotReadyException is thrown

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Android Studio. Please report it according to [these instructions](http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs/studio).